# What is the performance penalty of enabling stats on Guava Cache objects?

Tags: java, performance, caching, guava

Obviously, the correct answer is 'benchmark it and find out', but in the spirit of the internet, I'm hoping someone will have done the work for me.

I really like Guava's cache libraries for web services. Their docs are fairly vague on this point, however.

> **recordStats**
> `public CacheBuilder<K,V> recordStats()`
> Enable the accumulation of [`CacheStats`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheStats.html) during the operation of the cache. Without this `Cache.stats()` will return zero for all statistics. Note that recording stats requires bookkeeping to be performed with each operation, and thus imposes a performance penalty on cache operation.
>
> **Since:**
> 12.0 (previously, stats collection was automatic)

From JavaDocs for [`CacheBuilder.recordStats()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#recordStats%28%29).

I'm curious if the severity of the performance penalty is documented, benchmarked or ball-parked by anyone. I'm thinking it should be pretty minor, on the order of nanoseconds per operation. The cache operations themselves are already synchronized - reads don't lock or block, but writes do acquire locks - so no additional locking or concurrency should be required to modify the stats. That should limit it to a few additional increment operations per cache access.

The other side of it is perhaps some penalty when `Cache.stats()` is called. I'm planning on exposing the stats to persistent recording through Codahale MetricsRegistry and onto a Graphite server. The net effect is that the stats will be retrieved periodically, so if there's any blocking behavior on retrieval, that could be bad.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty minor; in fact, it used to be automatic (no way to opt out).

Comment: In the event that nobody has an answer and you take it upon yourself to do the benchmark, I hope you report your findings back here!

Comment: Right, @LouisWasserman, I snipped that from the doc quote when I first posted. But now that you mention it, it makes me think: if they bothered to change the stats collection, surely someone had an idea of the performance that could be gained by disabling it.

Comment: The penalty is ~10% to the read throughput, which records the hit/miss counts into a `LongAdder`. The stats are cheap to construct as its a non-blocking sum of values.

Comment: Keep the stats on and do not think about it! For http://cache2k.org I decided against making the stats optional,  because I do not like to put the users in the position to choose for either performance or "insight". OTOH the included statistics in cache2k are specifically designed to be low overhead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/google/guava/tree/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache):

#### What happens when we call `CacheBuilder.recordStats()`?

[`CacheBuilder`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.java) defines a no-op [`StatsCounter`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/AbstractCache.java#L137) implementation [`NULL_STATS_COUNTER`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.java#L158) and this is what is used by default.  If you call `.recordStats()` this is replaced with [`SimpleStatsCounter`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/AbstractCache.java#L199) which has six [`LongAddable`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LongAddable.java) fields (which is usually a [`LongAdder`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LongAdder.java) but falls back to an [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) if it can't use `LongAdder`) for each of the statistics it tracks.

#### Then what happens when we construct a `Cache`?

For a standard [`LocalCache`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java) (which is what you get from `CacheBuilder.build()` or `CacheBuilder.build(CacheLoader)`), it constructs an instance of the desired `StatsCounter` [during construction](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L262).  Each [`Segment`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L1974) of the `Cache` similarly gets [its own instance](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L311) of the same `StatsCounter` type.  Other `Cache` implementations can choose to use a `SimpleStatsCounter` if they desire, or provide their own behavior (e.g. a no-op implementation).

#### And when we use the `Cache`?

Every call into `LocalCache` that would impact one of the statistics calls the relevant `StatsCounter.record*()` methods, which in turn causes an atomic increment or addition on the backing `LongAddable`.  `LongAdder` is documented to be significantly faster than `AtomicLong`, so like you say this should be hardly noticeable.  Though in the case of the no-op `StatsRecorder` the JIT could optimize away the `record*()` calls entirely, which could *maybe* be noticeable over time.  But deciding not to track statistics on that basis would surely be [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

#### And finally when we get the statistics?

When you call [`Cache.stats()`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/LocalCache.java#L4840) the `StatsCounter`s for the `Cache` and all its `Segments` are [aggregated together](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/a34e7053d0b1db281893e0ec430f0d27ffa8e85e/guava/src/com/google/common/cache/AbstractCache.java#L261) in a new `StatsCounter` and the result returned to you.  This means there will be minimal blocking; each field only needs to be read once, and there's no external synchronizing or locking.  This does mean there's technically a race condition (a segment could be accessed midway through the aggregation) but in practice that's irrelevant.

#### So in summary?

You should feel comfortable using `CacheBuilder.recordStats()` on any `Cache` you're interested in monitoring, and calling `Cache.stats()` as frequently as is beneficial.  The memory overhead is roughly constant, the speed overhead is negligible (and faster than any similar monitoring you could likely implement), as is the contention overhead of `Cache.stats()`.

Obviously a dedicated thread doing nothing but calling `Cache.stats()` in a loop will cause some contention, but that would be silly.  Any sort of periodic access will go unnoticed.